# How can I truly enable inline editing on Detail tag?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a very simple VF page (below) but it does not really support Inline Editing.  When I double-click a field that should accept editing (with a pencil icon), the Save/Cancel buttons show up but the text-box does not show up.  Picklists, Lookups, check-boxes also do not work.

Beyond that, when I press Save, nothing happens.  The Save button goes light-grey but no actions take place.  The Cancel button works.

Is there a step I am missing that will actually activate inline editing or have I found a bug?

Note: The standard view page on the same Opportunity works as expected.

Note: Within the JS console, these two errors are displayed:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tab' of undefined main.js:1002`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Icons' of undefined`

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
   <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity}" inlineEdit="true" /> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where are you viewing the page?  Standard UI? Service Console?  Portal?

Comment: I am viewing it via https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/apex/OpportunityViewPage?id=006J000000DB5aU

Comment: I created the exact page you present above, and it works perfectly.  Is there any other code in your version?

Comment: The code is posted is exactly what I am testing with.  It was more complex before but I stripped it down to its bare bones to try to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Turns out it only fails in one of my Chrome browsers. It works fine in Firefox and on my other computer's Chrome. I disabled all plugins to no avail.

Comment: Try clearing cache ("Clear browsing data...", "Empty the cache" in Chrome) and logging in to a fresh session.

Comment: I tried logging out, clearing cache, logging back in and it still fails.  How odd, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you passing a valid opportunity ID in the URL?

Comment: Yes.  The Op I expect to show does show up.

Comment: After restarting the browser a few times, it appears to work now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

can you try give name to text control and buttons both the id and the name attributes. for example,

most browsers looking for both id and name for a form control